# htaccess Rewrite not working for https://www. to https://

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a unique situation on this wordpress site.  First for some reason, if certain pages don't have a trailing slash at the end of the URL, the site goes to a complete blank page.

Secondly, if the site does not resolve at http://example.com or https://example.com it shows up as a blank page.  So, if you go to www.domain.com or https://www.example.com it goes to a blank page.

We put in this code and it works to redirect everything BUT if someone types in https://www.example.com  If they type www.example.com it's good and it redirects where we want it which is https://example.com

The second set of code we need to add the trailing slash.

This site is hosted on GoDaddy and I contacted support and they suggested I go through the Wordpress database and search for instances of https://, but I couldn't understand what the point of that was.  The GoDaddy support rep said they were not able to resolve this.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
 RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```